# Как при сборке шаблона HTML-письма заинжектить в него стили?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, webpack, сборка

Мне нужно сверстать письма для рассылок, а в них желательно указывать стили инлайн. Есть ли возможность заменять в HTML/EGS-шаблоне классы на стили этого класса? Например, пишу в шаблоне:

```
<p class="style-font">
```

Есть класс (может подключаться к шаблону или быть прописан в нем):

```
.style-font {
  color: red;
  padding-top:0;
}
```

После сборки должен получиться HTML, в котором все классы заменены на стили:

```
<p style="color:red; padding-top:0;">
```

Что-то вроде миксинов в сам шаблон. Наверняка готовое решение уже есть...

Comment: Это называется `css inline`, можете использовать что-то наподобие [этого](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css).

Comment: @nazarpunk спасибо! Я так понимаю, рабочей обертки для вебпака у этого плагина нет?

Comment: У этого нет, но можно и с обёрткой [найти](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-style-plugin).